# how to extract current year and combine with specific month and date as a date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have to get the current year with June the 16th as a date.

For example, if I run the query now I want to get 2015-06-16.

I tried the following:

`CONVERT(DATETIME,cast( (cast(YEAR(GetDate()) AS VARCHAR(4))+'-06-16 00:00:00.000' as varchar (24) ),102)`

but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using sql-server? Have you seen the DATEADD function?

Comment: yes, sql-server, How to use DATEADD in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want your query to always return June 16th of the current year?

Comment: yes, the specific date is fixed

Comment: If you are using SQL server 2012 then you can use DateFromParts(Year(GetDate()),  6, 16). Check the link for further info : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx

Comment: `select dateadd(year, year(getdate())-2015, '20150616');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following T-SQL gives you the result you need.

`SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), YEAR(GetDate()))+'-06-16')`

Comment: Also: `SELECT CONVERT(date, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), GETDATE(), 112)+'0616');` (this will also work for dates before the year 1000). Your expression will need left padding with 0s to work for such dates.